# CSS Image Sprite Not Displaying Background Image

Tags: css, html, css-sprites

Hi I am having quite a bit of trouble getting this sprite to work. The background image never shows up and just displays the link text. I have tried to use direct paths to the image, http://.., but it still does not display correctly. I appreciate the help.

**CSS:**

```
    #social a {
      text-indent: -9000px;
      display: block;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

   #youtubelink a {
      background-image: url(social-btns.png);
      background-position: 0px 0px;
      width:46px;
      height:43px;
   }
   #youtubelink a:hover {
      background-position: 0px -43px;
   }
   #googlelink a {
      background-image: url(social-btns.png);
      background-position: 46px 0px;
      width:46px;
      height:43px;
   }
   #googlelink a:hover {
      background-position: 46px -43px;
   }
   #facebooklink a {
      background-image: url(social-btns.png);
      background-position: 92px 0px;
      width:46px;
      height:43px;
   }
   #facebooklink a:hover {
      background-position: 92px -43px;
   }
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="social" align="right">

       <a id="youtubelink" href="#">Youtube</a>

       <a id="googlelink" href="#">Google</a>

       <a id="facebooklink" href="#">Facebook</a>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have ids of anchor elements and you are selecting it as childs of them. You should do it like this:

```
a#facebooklink
```

The way you are using:

```
#facebooklink a
```

It will consider that anchor is child of `#facebooklink` and you have to change all of your SELECTORS.

Comment: Or since `id` is by definition unique, simply: `#facebooklink`. No need to slow down the selector by adding the element.

Comment: yeah but it is just for him to understand why is it ;)

Comment: Thanks everybody, I got it working. Its odd because I have made a sprite before using the way I did it here and it worked. I will keep it in mind for next time. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
#youtubelink a {
  // my css rules
```

}

It should be:

```
a#youtubelink {
      // my css rules
   }
```

The same applies to all of your three social links.

Answer (score 0):

That would be because your CSS is wrong. `#youtubelink a` means an anchor tag *inside* a tag with an id of "youtubelink". What you want is a#youtubelink